# Supporting custom Selenium IDE commands in a formatter

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-ide

I have managed to add custom commands to Selenium IDE, but am having difficulties supporting these in a format, namely, an extended version of the Python WebDriver format. In the script generated when exporting to my custom format, I get the following for the commands I've added:

`# ERROR: Caught exception [unknown command [finalPrice]]`

I've added this command to `user-extensions.js` as follows:

```
Selenium.prototype.doFinalPrice = function (locator) { return ''; }

CommandBuilders.add('action', function (window) {
    var result = {
        command: 'finalPrice',
        target: this.getRecorder(window).clickedElementLocators,
        execute: function () { return; },
        getDefinition: function () { return true; }
    };
    return result;
})
```

and extended the standard Python WebDriver `format.js` with the following:

```
WDAPI.Driver.prototype.finalPrice = function (locatorType, locator) {
    return ["#PRICE", locatorType, locator].join('|');
};

SeleniumWebDriverAdaptor.prototype.finalPrice = function () {
    var locator = this._elementLocator(this.rawArgs[0]);
    var driver = new WDAPI.Driver();
    return driver.finalPrice(locator.type, locator.string);
}
```

Has anyone managed to successfully do this and, if so, can you point out where I'm going wrong? As I've said, the command itself in Selenium IDE works fine, it's only the exporting to my custom format that fails. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to develop, in parallel javascript functions using user-extensions.js. This way the commands will exist for you both in webdriver AND selenium-ide. The cleanest way would be to create them once in user-extensions.js and then referencing that in webdriver.

Take a look at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/selenium-users/6Sfa1-bLKUQ/1fnoL4ZW3WoJ and https://bernardlago.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/user-extensions-with-selenium-rc-using-ruby-client-driver-selenium-client/ to understand how to bridge the gap to your custom javascript in user-extensions.

> What are user-extensions? These are JavaScript functions/libraries
>   that the user can create and use in order to extend Selenium.
>
> Why do we have to use user-extensions? Simple. If you want to add your
>   own actions, assertions and locator-strategies. This means that there
>   is currently no available command for the type of testing that you
>   would like to accomplish. This also implies that there is no method
>   yet in the Selenium API that will do the
>   action/assertion/locator-strategy that you would like to add.